# Is there a difference between "to update you" and "to keep you updated"?

Tags: phrase-choice

How should be use "update":

> I'll update you?
>   Keep me update or updated?

I'm not English and the system is considering me as it.

Comment: Suggestion: use google search with double quotation mark. - "keep me updated"

Answer (score 4):

If you are saying ***I will let you know if anything happens***, then you would say ***I will update you***, so you are correct here.

If you are saying ***Let me know if anything happens***, you would say ***Keep me updated***

Comment: This answer hits the nail on the head. One additional way to use the word would be "Give me an update." _Update_ can be a confusing word because it can be used as a noun or a verb.

Answer (score 1):

Both

> I'll update you.

and

> Keep me updat**ed**.

are acceptable.  "Update" is a transitive verb, you use it with an object: *update something* or *update somebody*.  '*Updated*' is a past participle that can be used where you can use an adjective.